# Find path from source to destination in tilt maze

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

For a tilt maze general reference, you can refer to [this example](https://www.mathsisfun.com/games/tilt-maze.html). The previous related code review discussion could be referred [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146469/data-structure-and-movement-for-tilt-maze-part-2/).

The problem I want to resolve is to find all possible path (so that in the future I can find minimal path) from source to destination.

My major idea is:

1. Represent the maze by flag which direction I can move from a specific cell
2. Using recursion, move left/right, then move top/down, then left/right, then top/down, until the destination is reached

I'm not sure if my implementation is elegant, move left/right, then move top/down, then left/right, then top/down, until reach to destination, seems a bit hard-coded way. I'm wondering if there are any functional/logical bugs in my code -- even if I tested, but might be potential issues which I do not find yet.

```
  __ __ __ __ 
 |__   |__   |          
 |  |  |     |           
 |  |   __|  |      
 |     |   __|            
 |__|__ __ __|         

class MoveEnum:
    CAN_MOVE_LEFT = 1
    CAN_MOVE_RIGHT = 2
    CAN_MOVE_UP = 4
    CAN_MOVE_DOWN = 8

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.results = []
    def move_left(self, x1, y1):
        while self.matrix[y1][x1] & MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT:
            x1 -= 1
        return (x1, y1)
    def move_right(self, x1, y1):
        while self.matrix[y1][x1] & MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT:
            x1 += 1
        return (x1, y1)
    def move_up(self, x1, y1):
        while self.matrix[y1][x1] & MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP:
            y1 -= 1
        return (x1, y1)
    def move_down(self, x1, y1):
        while self.matrix[y1][x1] & MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN:
            print y1
            y1 += 1
        return (x1, y1)
    # find shortest move from x1 y1, to x2, y2
    def move_path(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, is_left_right, path):
        if x1 == x2 and y1 == y2:
            self.results.append(path[:])
        elif is_left_right:
            (x, y) = self.move_right(x1,y1)
            if x != x1:
                path.append((x, y))
                self.move_path(x, y, x2, y2, not is_left_right, path)
                path.pop(-1)
            (x, y) = self.move_left(x1,y1)
            if x != x1:
                path.append((x, y))
                self.move_path(x, y, x2, y2, not is_left_right, path)
                path.pop(-1)
        else:
            (x, y) = self.move_up(x1, y1)
            if y != y1:
                path.append((x, y))
                self.move_path(x, y, x2, y2, not is_left_right, path)
                path.pop(-1)
            (x, y) = self.move_down(x1, y1)
            if y != y1:
                path.append((x, y))
                self.move_path(x, y, x2, y2, not is_left_right, path)
                path.pop(-1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    maze_matrix = [[MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN],
                   [MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN],
                   [MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP | MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN],
                    [MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP | MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN | MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP | MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN | MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_DOWN|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT],
                   [MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP|MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_UP | MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_RIGHT, MoveEnum.CAN_MOVE_LEFT]]
    maze = Maze(maze_matrix)
    maze.move_path(0,0,3,4,True,[])
    maze.move_path(0, 0, 3, 4, False, [])
    print maze.results
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd still suggest using a closure, which I addressed in my [last answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146643/42401):

> Your code is WET. As you write pretty much the same thing four times. Instead I'd use a builder function to remove this duplicate logic. This is as you can set the special changes in the builder function, and mutate the data in the returned function.
>
> Take:
>
> ```
> def _move(band, x_inc, y_inc):
>     def inner(x, y):
>         maze = self.maze
>         while maze[y][x] & band:
>             x += x_inc
>             y += y_inc
>         return x, y
>     return inner
>
> move_right = _move(2, 1, 0)
> ```

The name of `MoveEnum` could be changed to `Moves`, as the `Enum` part is useless when using it. I'd also change `CAN_MOVE_*` to just `*`, this is as it doesn't add any value. And so I'd much prefer it to be `Moves.UP`.

`move_path` is dodgy. You shouldn't have to pass a list to it, and it should really return `results`. Instead I would create another closure the outer function to create `path`, return `results`, and call the inner function. The inner function to perform the recursion as you currently have it.

Comment: Thanks Peilonrayz for the advices. Actually I have a high level question want to consult you, wondering if I need to record the places (cell x,y location) have been visited before? I have tested and there is no deadlock situation, but I am not confident if need a `visited` matrix as similar to what we did in BFS, DFS to avoid visit the same path again?

Comment: Hi Peilonrayz, trying to practice closure, and found your definition of `def _move(band, x_inc, y_inc):` does not need to have `self` as first parameter? Is it a typo or on purpose? Thanks.

Comment: For your **first comment** I didn't talk about `move_path` and won't. I mostly made this answer so I could reiterate my point. For you **second comment** I don't think you wrote it right, "found your definition of `_move` does not need to have `self` as first parameter?" If you meant (1) it doesn't need `self` as a parameter, then I'd respond with it doesn't. For (2) if you say it does, then if it's a class method _maybe_, look at my last answer. In this example I did make a mistake as in `inner` I use `self` where I should have used `global maze`, but it's not a method.

Comment: Thanks Peilonrayz, have you updated your code? Trying to see your comments in code -- "In this example I did make a mistake as in inner I use self", but cannot find out `self` any more?

Comment: Hi Peilonrayz , tried your code, but it has compile issue on this line -- `maze = self.maze`, which said `self` is not defined.

Comment: @LinMa I think your two comments answer each-other, ;P `maze = self.maze` is the `self` I'm on about

Comment: Thanks Peilonrayz, I found in your last post, you have `self` as input parameter for `inner` function, `def inner(self)`, but in your current post, you are using `x` and `y` as input parameter as `def inner(x, y)` -- this is why I am confused, could you clarify which form do you think is better?

Comment: BTW Peilonrayz, rewrite code including using closure, if you could comment on the new question, it will be great => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148211/find-path-from-source-to-destination-in-tilt-maze-part-2, and for the remaining open discussion on this thread, we can continue to discuss here.

Comment: There is no best. Either you create one that is used in a class `input(self, ...)` or you make one that is a plain function `input(...)`. Also can you not link me your posts, IMO it's rude, and you don't seem to want to use my suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Peilonrayz, mention your name since I think closure is a good idea and your credit, sorry if any confusion. I think I followed your idea to use closure (actually I am trying best to adopt, but met with the confusion of whether or not using `self`), which part do you think not following correctly for closure?

Comment: @linma I didn't just write about closures :) you can link your old question in new ones, just don't link them in comments